# Open all links within a div in a lightbox

Tags: lightbox

I'm trying to figure out how to open all of the images within a div in a lightbox. The div is pulling images from a picasa album, so I can't edit each link individually.

What would also work for me is the ability to open all links of a certain filetype in a lightbox.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the pretty gallery which meets your requirement.[Demo for photo gallery](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#prettyPhoto).

I have create a enlarge button on the photo gallery of the pikaChoose by clicking the button i display the gallery in light box. The code for display from pikaChoose is

```
 jQuery(".pika-stage #enlarge a").live('click',function(){ 
            jQuery.fn.prettyPhoto();            
            jQuery.prettyPhoto.open(api_gallery,api_titles,api_descriptions);
            return false;
             });
```

I hope this may be useful to you

Answer (score 0):

You can use lightbox:  http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

For example (first three lines in head - be sure to have the images like close button in imgs folder):

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="lightbox.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />    


<a href="img/image-2.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">Image #2</a>
<a href="img/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">Image #3</a>
<a href="img/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">Image #4</a>
```

Since you're using picasa, change the href to the appropriate link to the image.  If you're using php, then use for loops with echo, etc...